# Synchronize two YAML files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Is there any plugin to synchronize two YAML files ? For example file1 has

```
en:
   key1: "Value1"
   key2: "Value2"
es:
   key1: "EsValue1"
```

After synchronizing it needs to add key2: "Value2" in the second file without disturbing the order and the key1 in the second file.

Comment: Note that YAML maps are unordered, so preserving the order is not a YAML operation (which means that a conforming YAML parser may "forget" the order, and emit them in a different (possibly non-repeatable) order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a plugin to do it:

```
str = <<EOT
en:
  key1: "Value1"
  key2: "Value2"
es:
  key1: "EsValue1"
EOT

require 'yaml'
yaml = YAML::load(str)

(hash['en'].keys - hash['es'].keys).each{ |k| hash['es'][k] = hash['en'][k] }

>> ap hash #=> nil
{
    "en" => {
        "key1" => "Value1",
        "key2" => "Value2"
    },
    "es" => {
        "key1" => "EsValue1",
        "key2" => "Value2"
    }
}
```

If you have an arbitrary number of other hashes to process:

```
(yaml.keys - ['en']).each do |h|
  (yaml['en'].keys - yaml[h].keys).each do |k|
    yaml[h][k] = yaml['en'][k]
  end
end
```

So, read the YAML file, run the resulting hash through the code, then write the file again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will keep the order as you want, but if you use Ruby 1.9 it's pretty likely as it's using sorted hashes. You could read contents of the YAML files into hashes using `YAML.load_file` and then do something like this:

```
merger = proc { |key, v1, v2| Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : v2 }
es.merge(en, &merger)
```

and then dump es hash to the YAML file again.

This solution for recursive merging was suggested here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142809#635081

Comment: Ruby 1.9 doesn't use sorted hashes. It remembers the insertion order so if the elements aren't entered in a sorted order they won't come out in a sorted order.

Comment: Yeah, I meant _ordered_ hashes.